# receiving google playstore install referrer after i open the application

Tags: android

My question is:
 when will i receive a install referrer ,is it during the install time or after the app gets opened for the first time and what will happen if the user install the application and resets his phone without opening the app then is there a way to get the install referrer value.

Comment: When user will install and sign up for your app then you ll be able to receive who installed your app and with the reference of whom.